# ArrayList for handeling many Objects?

Tags: java, list, set

So I want to write a programm, that can manage workouts.I have a class "Excersise" and I will create many Objects from this class. Im wondering how I should handle all these Objects. Till now I had an ArrayList with all Excersises in it but when I want to add an Excersise to a workout, I would have to do it like this: `workout.add(excerises.get(index))` meaning I would have to know the index for every excerises. Also Im wondering how good the performany of ArrayLists are. Should I consider to use another data structure?

Comment: It is hard to answer your question with so little information. `...meaning I would have to know the index for every excerises.` There is currently no data structure in Java that knows which object you want by reading your mind, you will always need some kind of key to access specific data. You should have a look at `HashMaps` maybe they can solve your problem

Comment: `ArrayList` is good enough for `get(index)`.

Comment: The HashMap could also do the job but you'll still have to know what the key of the wanted object is (as any other data structure btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have constant pool of Excersises, and you only need to access them by index, then you can use array instead:

```
Excersise[] excersises = new Excersise[EXCERSIZE_SIZE];
//fill excersises
//use excersises
workout.add(excersises[index]);
```

ArrayList is designed to have fast access to element by index, and it is using array underneath, but it has range check inside it's get method. On the other hand ArrayList provide a bunch of useful methods, in case if you need any of them. The other thing is that if you would like to hold a lot of objects in it it might be wise to create it with some capacity, which you expect, knowing of how many objects you will add to this ArrayList, for example if you expect 1000 objects then you can do:

```
List<Excersise> excersises = new ArrayList(1000);
```

In that way you'll omit recreating of arrays inside ArrayList.add method when array inside ArrayList will not be able to store provided value (HashMap also has constructor `HashMap(int initialCapacity)`).

If you would like to access to excersise for example by it's symbolic name, let's say "push ups", then you can use HashMap:

```
Map<String, Excersise> excersiseByName = new HashMap<>();
//fill excersises
workout.add(excersiseByName.get("push ups"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will try the HashMap

Comment: I dont have a fixed size of excersises, so I cant use an array. I have another question, when I want to serialize my excersises, should I serialize the list where I collect all my excersises or should I serialize each excersise on its own and then deserialize each excersises and put it into my list when starting the application? Appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: You don't need to serialize each entry in HashMap or ArrayList manually - they know how to serialize themselves (and implement Serializable interface). Just make your Excersise serializable and serialize/decerialize `HashMap<String, Excersise>` or `ArrayList<Excersise>` as a whole